# Please help me to optmize this mysql query. It takes more time to load

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 
           f_workorders_shipments.date,
           f_inventory.id AS item_id,
           f_workorders_shipments.inventory_code AS code,
           f_inventory`.status,
           f_inventory.type,
           f_workorders.id AS order_id
         FROM f_workorders
         LEFT JOIN f_workorders_shipments
         ON f_workorders.id = f_workorders_shipments.order_id
         LEFT JOIN `f_inventory`
         ON f_workorders_shipments.inventory_code = f_inventory.code
         WHERE contact_id = "'.$_POST['id'].'"
         AND inventory_code IS NOT NULL
         ORDER BY due DESC'
```

Comment: How long in particular does it take?

Comment: What's the result of an [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html) query?

Comment: You must sanitize your user entered values used in the queries using `mysql_real_escape_string`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As joins are multiplicating the amount to rows to check, you must take care with indexing.

Please make an index for every field that is important to filter or to join with other field in other table.

A good indexing reduce the time to execute a sql command